# Simple sum of dropbox values for scoring Excel 2013 worksheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to make a worksheet with dropboxes for scoring ingredients and summing the scores per ingredient. I already made the dropboxes with number 1-3(1=poor, 2=fair, and 3=good), but I would like  after the values are selected for the score to be automatically totaled in the total column.

The dropbox is pulling from a table on the bottom which indicates
Bad   1
Fair 2
Good 3

I hope this is understood properly. I don't know any active x or VBA, so please keep this in mind. Please explain steps as simply and literally as possible.

[image][Click here for large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtg3Y.png)

Comment: What happens if you use `=SUM(B5:D5)` in cell `E5`?

Comment: @CharlieRB I tried that. it just shows "0". I need for the spreadsheet to recognize the values inputed through the dropdown. Then sum in e5.

Comment: How did you create the dropdown lists? Judging by your screenshot, I'm thinking you added controls. Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you need to use drop-down list? You could use data validation with the same functionality and excel would recognize the values in formulas.

Comment: @CharlieRB I inserted a combo box from form controls.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Because my manager wants to be able to select the fields on a tablet through dropdowns and have them summed up. That is what she asked for. I'd really hate to say, "I can't do it", even though I am pretty sure it is possible.

Comment: It looks nice, but as you have found out, makes it very difficult to sum values. [Data validation](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9) (about half way down) allows for lists for making selections. Excel can sum these values. Using the current controls, it will be a steep learning curve for you to get those summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kinds of controls are those? The easiest solution is to add Form Controls (as opposed to ActiveX Controls).

[image: Insert Form Control]

After that, right-click on them and click on "Format Control..." at the bottom of the context menu. In the window that opens, go to the "Control" tab - if you're not there already - and select a range for the "Cell link:" field.

[image: Set Cell Link]

Now, any value selected in the combo box will *also* be in that linked cell. From your screenshot, you could set the linked cell to the cell directly behind the control so that the control hides the text from the user. Your formula can then sum those values.

---

The "Input range:" property is where the drop-down list comes from. You'll have to type your list in some cells somewhere and then reference them here.

Comment: They have already created the controls. They are trying to SUM them.

Comment: @CharlieRB Then they just need to set the linked cell. However, it really matters if they added a Form Control or an ActiveX control. I know what OP said in the comments but I wanted to be clear and complete in my answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how to do this.

Comment: @CharlieRB It already explains that. Is it not clear? The paragraph above and below the second screenshot talk about exactly that.

Comment: @EngineerToast thank you. I will try this. Btw, it was a form control.

Comment: @CharlieRB could you advise as to how one would do this using data validation, jic? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you did. I was focused on your starting your answer with a question. Clarification should always be done in the comments area.

Comment: @Christina The only reason I didn't was because you were looking for an answer for what you already have in place. I didn't want to create confusion. The link I provided explains how to use it. This answer is a good solution too.

Comment: @CharlieRB thank you for your comments and assistance!